# Solving second order differential equation numerically with values given at intermediate points.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to numerically solve the equation,
\begin{equation}
y''(x) + p(x)y(x) = 1
\end{equation}

in the range [a,b]

with conditions
\begin{eqnarray}
y'(\alpha) &=& 1\\
y(\beta) &=& 0  \hspace{1cm} a <\alpha < \beta <b
\end{eqnarray}

if the conditions were given for either of the endpoints, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
y'(a) &=& 1\\
y(a) &=& 0  
\end{eqnarray}

I can find $y(a+\Delta x)$ using these conditions and rest of the solution can
be found from discretization,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{y(x+\Delta x) - 2y(x) + y(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x^2} + p(x)y(x) = 1
\end{eqnarray}

But if initial value/derivatives are known at different points(that are not successive in discretization) then how can I proceed?

Comment: It looks like a [Shooting Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) in $\left(\alpha,\beta\right)$ could be helpful.

Comment: Maybe method of characteristics could be useful.

Comment: Yes, shooting method seems to fit (linked above). You vary the initial conditions on one end $y_z(\alpha) = z, y_z'(\alpha) = 1$ and try to find the $z$ that would bring $y_z(\beta)$ to $0$. (Using any root finding algorithm).

Or, theoretically, for given $p(x)$ you could try to find (numerically) the solution via [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can proceed in two different manners:

- Solve the problem in the grid corresponding to $x\in [\alpha,\beta]$ and then solve the two initial value problems given by:
  $$y_L''+p(x) y_L=1,  \quad a < x < \alpha, \quad y_L(\alpha) = y(\alpha),  \quad y_L'(\alpha) = y_L(\alpha) \tag{1}$$
  $$y_R''+p(x) y_R=1,   \quad \beta < x < b, \quad y_R(\beta) = y(\beta), \quad y_R'(\beta) = y_R(\beta) \tag{2}$$
  on different suitable grids. Note that the problem for $y_L$ moves backwards and the change of variable $z \equiv \alpha -x$ can fix this issue. Besides, note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are initial value problems for which you may or may not use another numerical method to solve them.
- The other option would be, provided you adapt your mesh so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nodes of the grid, to subsitute the discretized boundary conditions at $x=\alpha$ and $\beta$ while $y_0$ and $y_{N}$ (first and last values of $y_j \approx y(x_j)$) remains unknown (I think this approach is a bit more tedious).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!